# align text div directly over input's text

Tags: jquery, html

I need to fade-in an `input` text field's text directly over a `div` with selfsame text.

I can request the offset of the `div`, and position the `input` at the same spot.  However, it does not align correctly (the `div` appears nestled in the top left corner of the `input`).  I've only been able to make the text align by nudging them by hand.

```
<input id="ip" type="text" value="Optimus Prime"></input>
<div id="op">Optimus Prime</div>
var absTopLeft = {
    height: '33px',
    fontSize: '15px',
    fontFamily: "Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif",
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
};
$("#ip").css( absTopLeft );
$('#op').css( absTopLeft );
```

[image]

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5Ck/)

There has to be a better way.  Especially if I set the height of the `input` to something irregular or center the `input`'s text.  What is that better way?

Comment: Any particular reason you're defining CSS elements in JS?, when you can do them using CSS? You can tweak to overlay, but it may have different effects in different browsers/devices unless you reset the CSS and apply.

Comment: Probably you can't do it pixel-perfect, because different browsers will behave differently. But why do you want to do that? I think this is [**the XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Oriol: it is the same font, same font size, same font attributes.  They can most likely be laid directly on top of each other with very little variation.  It is the input field which has a bulky box around it I need to account for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS-only solution.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="ip" type="text" value="Optimus Prime"></input>
    <div id="op">Optimus Prime</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#ip, #op {
    width: 200px;
    height: 33px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', 'Georgia', serif;
}

#op {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5Ck/1/)

It looks aligned on Firefox 25.

Keep in mind that browsers have different default `<input>` styling, so this will probably be off by a few pixels everywhere else. Try to normalize your styled elements as much as possible (override as many known default styles that you can); or use a CSS reset like [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: Yeah, you can improve this. Try including normalize.css on your site and then tweak my styles to get it lined up correctly. Maybe change the border size slightly.

Comment: No, I mean I get that in the jsfiddle (and I'm not the asker of the question).

Comment: Whoops, I didn't read your username :*) I updated my fiddle to include normalize.css and it looks nice to me: http://jsfiddle.net/kw5Ck/2/ Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/lx72D8N.png

Comment: Firefox 28 may also have different styling than 25 does.

Comment: Ah, I understood that asker wanted the two texts to overlap perfectly... @jedierikb can you clarify?

Comment: Hoping to make Optimus Prime appear 'only once' as the glyphs would be perfectly stacked

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well (perfect alignment in safari/chrome), but there is still a 1px vertical and horizontal offset in Firefox.

```
var absTopLeft = {
    fontSize: '15px',
    fontFamily: "Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif",
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
};
var ip = $("#ip"),
    op = $("#op");
ip.css( absTopLeft );
ip.css( 'height', 33 );
ip.css( 'color', 'green' );
op.css( absTopLeft );
op.css( 'color', 'red' );

var ipBorderLeft = parseInt( ip.css('border-left-width'), 10 ),
    ipPaddingLeft = parseInt( ip.css('padding-left'), 10 ),
    ipTextIndent = parseInt( ip.css('text-indent'), 10 ),
    ipMarginLeft = parseInt( ip.css('margin-left'), 10 );

op.css( 'left', ipBorderLeft + ipPaddingLeft + ipTextIndent + ipMarginLeft );

var htDiff = ip.outerHeight() - op.outerHeight();
op.css( 'top', htDiff/2 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3D3tM/